# Can I customize the error message displayed when React Player cannot play a video?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-video, react-player

I have a use case for React Player (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) where the video that is being displayed from a Cloudfront presigned URL might not exist.

Currently, when the user tries to play the non-existent video, they see the message "No video with supported format and MIME type found."

Is there a way to customize this message in some way, to something like "Please upload a video?"

Answer (score 0):

From the React Player docs

> onError - Called when an error occurs whilst attempting to play media

Using that with conditional rendering, you can easily customize the Cloudfront error message.

Here's quick demo I did to show how it works on codesandbox. Play around with it to see how it works.

[React Player Demo - Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fragrant-monad-tdsncn?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Freact-player%2FReactPlayer.tsx%3A12%2C62&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8v0002z3b6fytcxktaf%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8uz002w3b6fxk7oe0jl%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8uz002y3b6fg7qv9pee%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8uz002x3b6fui4snzip%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B56.89326341472761%252C43.10673658527239%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrssb8uz002w3b6fxk7oe0jl%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8uz002w3b6fxk7oe0jl%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsxa9oe00023b6fo2hkrgyq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A62%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A62%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Freact-player%252FReactPlayer.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrsxa9oe00023b6fo2hkrgyq%2522%257D%252C%2522clrssb8uz002x3b6fui4snzip%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8uz002x3b6fui4snzip%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsq3ndu00043b6fsxgdtpzd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrsq3ndu00043b6fsxgdtpzd%2522%257D%252C%2522clrssb8uz002y3b6fg7qv9pee%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrssb8uz002y3b6fg7qv9pee%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)